# Shrink Automation

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

My script to push the OS partition resize, e.g.

```
Resize-Partition -DiskNumber 2 -PartitionNumber 1 -Size (60GB)
```

If I get an error because windows cannot shrink to the desired size ("there is not enough space to perform action") then try

```
Resize-Partition -DiskNumber 2 -PartitionNumber 1 -Size (70GB)
```

and the loop keeps going until the partition is resized.

Question is how do I set the conditions using pwshell?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to increase the target size step by step until the operation is successful? Looks to me like you already know what you need to do, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tested a few script which are not working. I need an if condition that would automate the above. Action is to resize the partition, but if windows error appears then increase the shrink size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an overview of what you need to do:

1. Set a variable to the desired size of the partition.
2. Loop until you succeed or the desired size is the current size of the partition.
3. In the loop, try to resize the partition to the size in the variable.

   - If the attempt fails, use some algorithm to move toward the actual size of the partition.

Here is my code (you may want to save this to a `.ps1` file and import it if you are new to PowerShell functions.)

```
Function Resize-PartitionDynamic
{
    param(
    [int] $diskNumber,
    [int] $PartitionNumber,
    [long] $Size
    )

    $currentSize = $size
    $successful = $false
    $maxSize = (get-partition -DiskNumber 0 -PartitionNumber 1).size

    # Try until success or the current size is 
    # the size of the existing partition
    while(!$successful -and $currentSize -lt $maxSize)
    {
        try
        {
            Resize-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -PartitionNumber $PartitionNumber -Size $currentSize -ErrorAction Stop
            $successful = $true
        }
        catch
        {
            # Record the failure and move the size
            # half way to the size of the current partition
            # feel free to change the algorithm move closer to the
            # current size to something else... 
            # there probably should be a minimum move size too
            $lastError = $_
            $currentSize = $Size + (($maxSize - $successful)/2)             
        }
    }

    # If we weren't successful, throw the last error
    if(!$successful)
    {
        throw $lastError
    }
}
```

Here is an example of using the function:

```
Resize-PartitionDynamic -diskNumber 2 -PartitionNumber 3 -Size 456GB
```

Comment: I tested it and found a couple of bugs, which I have fixed, but I did not get the error you hit.

Comment: Thank you, this is the error exact I get: system32>     param(
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList

Comment: I saved the exact sample above as a gist on github.  Right click on [this link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TravisEz13/c0e8c31e6c39351baae833a6e633b1b9/raw/34c3bccc844a1247f164f499cbe8c2d74d52e357/sd42004026.ps1) and save as.   You should have a file `sd42004026.ps1` at that point.  In PowerShell `cd` to the directory you saved the file and run `. .\sd42004026.ps1`.  The above function should now be in scope and you should be able to use it like `Resize-PartitionDynamic -diskNumber 3 -PartitionNumber 4 -Size (999GB)`

Comment: Thank you for the kind support.